Suppress scrolling
I'd like to fit stuff some to the current window and want suppress scrolling completely. So the last line displayed in the window should correspond to the last line of the buffer. And if the the point reaches this last line there should be no scrolling happening whatsoever. How can this be done?

@phils Wow, the narrow-to-region does the trick! Great, thank you so much!!!

Very good; I'll make that an Answer then.

If you want display only the bottom-most portion of the buffer which currently fits into the window, you can use:
(save-excursion
  (widen)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (recenter -1)
  (narrow-to-region (window-start) (point-max)))

You would need to do this whenever the buffer contents or window size changed.
See C-hig (elisp)Window Hooks for how to react when a window size or configuration changes (for whichever arbitrary reason).
